# Without scroll bar and box

Tags: html, css

1. How can the picture be static without a scroll bar?
2. And how do I get a box in the middle of the picture? Because I have to write that the homepage is under construction.

This is the homepage: http://odsgaardklausen.dk/DBS/DBS.php

Hope that someone can help me :D

From Kamilla :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the image as a background on the `body`

for example:

```
body { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

A good article can be found on [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: Thank you. But, when I use your code, it does not show my whole picture on the desktop or the mobile :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `img` tag, set the image on the surrounding `div` as a background-image and assign `background-size: cover;` and `height: 100vh;` (plus some more styles for vertical centering, see fiddle at end of this answer).

For the message box in the middle, put another `div` inside your `div` that has the background-image, and give it the following styles:

```css
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
color: white;
text-align: center;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eydLkepa/1/

If you want the full solution (and only start adapting styles): https://jsfiddle.net/eydLkepa/3/

Answer (score 0):

```css
(Selector (Div or else)) { 
  background: url(image path) no-repeat center center fixed;   
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

you set background image by doing this now for  you can apply the text styles as per you recommendation to show between in the center you can apply.

```css
(Selector for text div){
  z-index:'';
  color:'';
  font-size:'';
  top : 50%;
  left:50%;
  etc.. etc...
}
```